# How to disable vscode's inbuilt suggestions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[image: Picture of VS Code]

I only want to keep the `consoleLog` but I want the rest gone. I've disabled all extensions and those suggestions are still there. I have no idea which language's suggestions are those but I want them gone. Just the vscode's inbuilt suggestions not the extensions' suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the little icon that precedes each entry and finding it here: [types of completions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions) - those are `variables` suggestions.

So you can specifically disable those with

> Editor > Suggest: Show Variables